# non-static method start() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

When I'm trying to add Start and Cancel in the button I get this error.
I looked into the Timer files but I didn't see anything
"error: non-static method start() cannot be referenced from a static context"

```
public int number;

public TextView textfield;

Button buton;

int x = 1;

Boolean y = false;



@Override

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading);

    new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            textfield.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textfield.setText("Time is up");
        }
    }.start();

    textfield=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Zamanlayici);

    buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Click);

    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {


           //My Error is in there :(
          if (y) {
                CountDownTimer.start();
                y= true;
            }
            else {
                y = false;
                CountDownTimer.cancel();

            }
        }
    });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `CountDownTimer` to call non-static methods from it.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();
timer.start();
```

Change your code to this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading);
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textfield.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            textfield.setText("Time is up");
        }
    }
    timer.start();

    textfield=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Zamanlayici);
    buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Click);
    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (y) {
                timer.start();
                y= true;
            }
            else {
                y = false;
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: local varriable timer is accessed from within inner class; needs to be decleared final

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use not static method like a static. Try to create a variable to store instance of CountDownTimer and call methods on it. Also doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of CountDownTimer, like so:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000){...}
```

Then, in the onClick method:

```
if (y) {
   timer.start();
   y= true;
}
else {
   y = false;
   timer.cancel();

}
```

Comment: Error:(55, 21) error: local variable t is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final